# Are there any benefits to use infinite scroll, when you're using hard code or static items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

I know that using infinite scrolling can be useful when you're fetching data from API. But assume you fetched data from API and stored in redux inside the parent component and passed items as props to child component like this:

```
//This is parent component. Assume items are fetched from API
<Items lots={items}/>
```

Child component:

```
const Items = ({lots}:{lots:any[]})={
//I want to use infinite scroll for items.
}
```

My question: Are there any benefits to use infinite scroll like that? Does this make the website faster? Does it make the website user friendly? In another words do I make the same profit when I'm using this approach instead of using infinite scroll for fetched data directly?

Comment: I believe here you should look to use virtualization for lesser DOM elements.

Comment: I'm using infinite scroller https://github.com/danbovey/react-infinite-scroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any benefits to using infinite scroll?

It depends on how you implement your scroll, a good way to optimize scroll performance is to virtualize it.

[image: virtualized list]

The idea behind virtualized scrolling is to display only visible items and a little more sometimes.

Even if you have static items if you have 10 000 static items using virtualize scroll will help you. This is a UI performance improvement and it does not relate to how you get the data and how you store it.

Here are some libraries that are implementing this with react:

- https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window
- https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

If you want to know more about this here is an article on [web.dev](https://web.dev/virtualize-long-lists-react-window/)

Comment: tnx . I'm using another component called react-infinite-scroller https://github.com/danbovey/react-infinite-scroller .It works like the right picture (virtualizid scrolled). "This is a UI performance improvement and it does not relate to how you get the data and how you store it." this sentence solved my problem.Thank you

Comment: I'll add https://github.com/danbovey/react-infinite-scroller to the answer if you are ok ?

Comment: tnx. Your answer is comprehensive and effective. no need to change